# modinfo: ERROR: Module udl not found

Tags: arch-linux, display, displaylink

Error occurs when running `modinfo udl`

Using kernel 6.4.11-arch2-1.

In my config I have:

```
CONFIG_DRM_UDL=m
# CONFIG_FB_UDL is not set
```

`modinfo udlfb` returns the same error.

This problem arose when debugging an issue with displaylink. Displaylink does not run at all and I believe it is due to the udl module missing. I have followed all debugging steps on the archlinux wiki and anything eles I can find on here/google.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

- for module **udlfb** as you stated above, the error is "right" because it has not been compile (as module) since the kernel option `# CONFIG_FB_UDL is not set`
- module **udl** is included in (latest) linux packages (both *-lts* and *-zen*), thus should be on your disk here;
  I have both the above-mentioned kernel installed, so if I search for it, I find there:

```
$ sudo find /  | grep  udl.ko
/usr/lib/modules/6.1.45-1-lts/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/udl/udl.ko.zst
/usr/lib/modules/6.4.12-zen1-1-zen/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/udl/udl.ko.zst
```

so, question is: are you sure file **udl.ko.zst** is present on your machine?
*please, before check, update your entire system*

Comment: Many thanks for your response. 

`sudo find /  | grep  udl.ko`

returns

`/usr/lib/modules/6.4.12-arch1-1/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/udl/udl.ko.zst`. So the module is present, but why is it not recognised?

Comment: very interesting but I have no idea... `modinfo` looks for it elsewhere... did you reboot your machine?

Comment: `modinfo' now shows that udl is running - I have no idea what fixed this. The issue had persisted for a while so I'm pretty sure it wasn't lack of reboot. Thanks for your help!